# Tag deletion request: register

Tags: support, retag-request

As shown on https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/register

There are only 16 questions tagged with [register](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/register).

Within them, I found the following "meanings" for register:

- register as Registry
- CPU registers
- Registering software
- DLL registration

Noting the lack of a proper definition in the tag info page and the number of questions actually using the tag, I don't see any reason why it should exist as is.

Comment: I've retagged a couple of the questions that were specific to CPU registers as [tag:cpu-architecture], since "cpu-register" is included in that.